# Check Different Range Before Running Code

Tags: vba, excel

I just signed up because I couldn't find an answer to my problem anywhere and it has been driving me crazy. I have a code (below) that I am trying to get to run only if a different range meets the criteria. In Column "L" I have a date, if the date is less than 14 days away the cell will be highlighted and bold. However, I only need to run this code if the cell in column "M" is blank. "L" is the due by date for a project and "M" is the completed date. So if "M" has been completed and has a date then I do not need for "L" to be formatted because it is already completed. Here is my current code:

```
Sub InvestigationAlertMsg()

Sheets("Investigations").Select
Dim Msg As String
'Set test = Range("M2:M1000").Find(What:="")


For Each cell In Range("L2:L1000")
'If Range("M2:M1000").Text <> "" Then
        If cell.Value < Date + 14 And cell.Value <> "" Then
            If Msg = "" Then
                Msg = "Investigation(s) Due in <14 Days"
            End If
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        cell.Font.Bold = True
        ElseIf cell.Value > Date + 14 Then
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        cell.Font.Bold = False
        'ElseIf Range("M2:M1000").Text <> "" Then
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
'End If
Next

If Msg <> "" Then MsgBox Msg, vbOKOnly, "Attention"


End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot of my cells

[image: Screenshot]

When a project gets approved, the date of approval will be inputted in "M". When that happens, the "due date" or "L" becomes irrelevant therefore I wouldn't need to format it any longer, it would not need a fill.

Comment: Can you specify the problem? Your code doesn't work? If so, where does it throw an error? Are you geting wrong results after running a macro? If you could attach screenshots with base values/expected result/actual result, that would be much of help.

Comment: Within your loops, you can refer to *M* cells as **Cell.Offset(0,1).Value**

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I don't get an error in the code, but the code doesn't run how I would like it to run. I'll add a screenshot in  the question. @AntiDrondert

Answer (score 1):

Use this to test the cell in the next column:
`If cell.offset(0,1).value="" then`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you asking, but here you go:

```
Sub InvestigationAlertMsg()
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim wsInvest As Worksheet, iCell As Range
    Set wsInvest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Investigations")

    For Each iCell In wsInvest.Range("M2:M1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(0, -1)
        If iCell.Value < Date + 14 And iCell.Value <> "" Then
            If Msg = "" Then _
                Msg = "Investigation(s) Due in <14 Days"
            iCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            iCell.Font.Bold = True
        ElseIf iCell.Value > Date + 14 Then
            iCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            iCell.Font.Bold = False
            iCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next

    If Msg <> "" Then _
        MsgBox Msg, vbOKOnly, "Attention"
End Sub
```

Comment: That is beautiful.  I never think to embed a desired `If` in the `For` statement.  So efficient.  Mind.  Blown.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `'If Range("M2:M1000").Text <> "" Then`with this code

```
If Range("M" & cell.Row).value = "" Then
```